# Неправильная работа якорей

Tags: html

Почему при клике на элемент, открывается новая страница вместо того, чтобы плавно скролить к соответствующему разделу на текущей странице?

В body в самом вверху вставляю меню:

```css
/* Стили для меню навигации */

.nav {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 0.95em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.418);
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">Секция 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Секция 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Секция 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4">Секция 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section5">Секция 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section6">Секция 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section7">Секция 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section8">Секция 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section9">Секция 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section10">Секция 10</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

и прописываю `id="section1"` в дивах блоков:

```
<div class="block" id="section1">
...
...
</div>
```

Но при клике в меню навигации у меня открывается новая страница, но никак не скролится, почему?

Answer (score 0):

Вот у меня всё работает, при нажатии на Секцию 1 проматывает вниз

```css
/* Стили для меню навигации */

.nav {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 0.95em;top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.418);
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">Секция 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Секция 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Секция 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4">Секция 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section5">Секция 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section6">Секция 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section7">Секция 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section8">Секция 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section9">Секция 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section10">Секция 10</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="section1">Якорь</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все должно работать

```css
/* Стили для меню навигации */

.nav {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 0.95em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.418);
}

.section {
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">Секция 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Секция 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Секция 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4">Секция 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section5">Секция 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section6">Секция 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section7">Секция 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section8">Секция 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section9">Секция 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section10">Секция 10</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div>
  <div class="section" id="section1">section1</div>
  <div class="section" id="section2">section2</div>
  <div class="section" id="section3">section3</div>
  <div class="section" id="section4">section4</div>
  <div class="section" id="section5">section5</div>
  <div class="section" id="section6">section6</div>
  <div class="section" id="section7">section7</div>
  <div class="section" id="section8">section8</div>
  <div class="section" id="section9">section9</div>
  <div class="section" id="section10">section10</div>

</div>
```